# Can I use map function with 2 arrays?

Tags: javascript, arrays, dictionary, zipwith

I was wondering if any function exist that can do something like that

I already tried zipWith and some variations of the map, but no good results.
Only working solution to this is 2x ForEach, but I was wondering if I can minimalize this to one function

```
_.map( (array1, array2), function(knownValue, indexOfArray1, indexOfArray2) );
```

What I need is to increase array1 and array 2 indexes simultaneously (like: a1: 1, a2: 1; a1: 2, a2: 2; ...).

This arrays have also other types of values

@EDIT

I messed a little.
What i really wanted is to make this wrongly writed code to work

```
_.map( (array1, array2), (valueOfArray1, valueOfArray2), someFunction(knownValue, valueOfArray1, valueOfArray2) );
```

So my intention is: 
For array1 and array2 elements, execute the function "someFunction", and in the next increment, use the next element of each array.

Like :

```
_.map( (array1, array2), (array1[0], array2[0]), someFunction(knownValue, array1[0], array2[0]) );
```

and next

```
_.map( (array1, array2), (array1[1], array2[1]), someFunction(knownValue, array1[1], array2[1]) );
```

but I want it more elegant :P

PS (Sorry for this mess)

Comment: Just `concat` the two arrays, then use `map`

Comment: I think you can use `for (let i = 0; i < arr1.length: i++) { ... arr1[i]; ... arr2[i]... }`

Comment: You can use the index of first array to access the elements in the seconds array, if both of them are equal in length.

Comment: Can you please clarify the output a bit? *"I need to increase array1 and array 2 indexes simultaneously*" Are you trying to loop through each index and do something? Create a new array? Do they both have the same number of elements? It's unclear

Comment: @adiga 
Yes they have the same number of elements

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is an example with `flatMap`:

```js
const arr1 = [1,3,5];
const arr2 = [2,4,6];

console.log(arr1.flatMap((x,i) =>[x, arr2[i]]))
```

Answer (score 1):

Since you already seem to be using lodash (or something similar) the `.zip` should work. The only pitfall is that `.zip` produces "pairs" with one from each original array IN a new array.

So when you map over the result from the `.zip`, the first argument is an array. See the example below and note that I'm destructuring the first argument with

```
function([a1_item, a2_item], indexForBoth) { .. rest of function here }
```

```js
const a1 = ['a', 'b', 'c'];
const a2 = ['One', 'Two', 'Three'];

const result = _.zip(a1, a2).map(function([a1_item, a2_item], indexForBoth) { 
  return a1_item + a2_item + indexForBoth;
});


console.log("a1", a1);
console.log("a2", a2);
console.log("a1 zipped with a2", _.zip(a1, a2) );

console.log("Result after mapping and concatinating", result);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/lodash@4.17.11/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Since they both have the same number of items, you can loop through `array1` using `map`. The second parameter of `map` callback is the index. You can use it to get the equivalent value from `array2` using `array2[index]`

```
array1.map((value1, index) => someFunction(knownValue, value1, array2[index]))
```

This creates an array of values returned by `someFunction` for each index

Here's a snippet with some sample data. Here, `someFunction` concatenates each value with a `_` seperator

```js
const someFunction = (...values) => values.join('_')

const array1 = [1, 2, 3],
      array2 = [10, 20, 30],
      knownValue = "fixed";

const output = array1.map((value1, i) => someFunction(knownValue, value1, array2[i]))

console.log(output)
```